# Возврат индекса из кортежа | Python | Tuple | Index

Tags: python, строки, tuple

**Good afternoon, dear friends!**

Помогите, пожалуйста...

Есть кортеж:

```
a = ("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
```

User вводит: `"Mon"`.
Каким образом можно вернуть идекс значения "Mod", т.е. `0`  ???

Comment: Не используя isoweekday******

Comment: `a.index("Mon")`

Comment: @entithat Вы гений!